# Why does when calling the reset() function, other functions that are onclick on the button stop working?

Tags: javascript, css, function, button, onclick

Trying to build my first "quizAPP". The reset function doesn't let me click other buttons when clicked.
Here is my code: https://codepen.io/Leonyr/pen/eYLEEgq

```
function reset() {
    num = 1;
    let img = document.querySelector('#img');
    img.src = `${baseUrl}${num}.png`
    nextBtn.disabled = false;
    nextBtn.style.color = '#555b6e'
    nextBtn.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
    spanNumber.innerText = num;

    for(let i=0; i < allBtn.length; i++){
        // allBtn[i].classList.add('reset');
        allBtn[i].classList.remove('chozen', 'dizabled')
        allBtn[i].style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
    }
}
```

I tried creating a function that removes the classes and resets the pointerEvents.

Comment: Well did you disable all the button too???? hint hint hint `allBtn[i].disabled=true;`

Comment: added  allBtn[i].disabled = false; to the loop but still I can't select any after clicking the reset button

Answer (score 0):

By taking a look at your code, one problem you have is that when you are clicking on one of the "answer buttons", the `chosen()` function gets called. Now in the `chosen()` function the following loop gets executed:

```js
for(let i = 0; i < allBtn.length; i++){
     allBtn[i].disabled = true;
     allBtn[i].classList.add('dizabled')
}
```

You are disabling **every** "answer button" and never renabling them again. A disabled button is unusable and un-clickable, meaning that the `chosen()` function will not called anymore since the `click` event will not be fired. In order to fix this you could renable them when you click on the reset button:

```js
function reset(){
    num = 1;
    let img = document.querySelector('#img');
    img.src = `${baseUrl}${num}.png`
    nextBtn.disabled = false;
    nextBtn.style.color = '#555b6e'
    nextBtn.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
    spanNumber.innerText = num;
    for(let i=0;i<allBtn.length;i++){
        // allBtn[i].classList.add('reset');
        allBtn[i].classList.remove('chozen','dizabled')
        allBtn[i].style.pointerEvents='auto';

        allBtn[i].disabled = false; // renabling button 
    }
}
```

Comment: I did this, and still the same issue but now the buttons are enabled but still can't select them(the red shadowbox when clicking)